# F5/output command no longer works

Tags: texniccenter

All of a sudden the output button <kbd>F5</kbd> won't work.

The TeX file compiles just fine and a new `.pdf` is in fact generated in the storage folder on the flashdrive. But hitting the <kbd>F5</kbd>-key now forces a warning window to pop up on my screen saying

> "Cannot execute the command" with "[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.p..."

appearing above it.

Comment: any issue with keybindings such as F5  is purely a problem in your editor but you don't say what editor you are using. tex itself does not have any such keybindings and the error message you quote is not a tex error.

Comment: you mind stating your editor?

Comment: what editor are you using and which operating system? On Windows you can't change files when they are opened in another program, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I guess you did an update before? Update for Windows, TeXnicCenter oder MiKTeX?  I could not be that this error suddenly happens, there must be a cause for it.  Please describe your problem better. Include the version numbers for TeXnicCenter, MiKTeX and Windows. For other readers: op uses TeXnicCenter ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave us no version numbers of your used TeX distribution and TeXnicCenter I can only guess.

For me it seems you are using an older version of TeXnicCenter, because you showed us an older DDE command.  In the stable version TeXniccenter 2.02 you should configure your output profile like this (see red markings!):

[image: configuration for viewer]

Use the DDE command `[Open("%tm.pdf",0,1,1)]` (please see that I changed the `%bm` to `%tm`), use the server name `sumatra`, `control` for Thema (engl. theme?) and change for ForewardSearch also `%bm` to `%tm`.

If you do not want to update to the current version (why not?) change the shown `%bm` to `%tm` too.

This change becomes neccessary because there was an changing in MiKTeX causing this.

More information you can get on the TeXnicCenter Homepage (meanings of parameters `tm` and `bm`) and about the configuration of [TeXnicCenter for SumatraPDF.](http://william.famille-blum.org/blog/static.php?page=static081010-000413)

With this changing TeXnicCenter is able to locate and show the resulting PDF file.

BTW: change `%bm` to `%tm` also for (La)TeX configuration (BibTeX and MakeIndex)!